Removing T4MVC from razor views in ASP.NET MVC
We have a ASP.NET MVC project that uses T4MVC, which we want to remove. So we have code like this all over the views
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Accounting.XeroSync.Index())">Sync</a>

Which we want to revert to
<a href="/Accounting/XeroSync/Index">Sync</a>

If there are no other options we will do this manually, but there are hundreds of different spots in the code using this, so I was wondering if anyone had experience removing this from code before. For example if you created a regex of some kind that could search replace.
